# Datatable always retrieving first record of the table in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am performing search operation based on id which is auto incremented when I enter id as 0 it is retrieving data which is having id 1.

This is the search method

```
public DataTable Search(int code=0)
    {
        SqlConnection con = sqlConnection;
        String Query = "Select * from person" + (code > 0 ? " where code =" + code : "");
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Temp");
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            con.Close();
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

This is search button code

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtSearchCode.Text.Length>0)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new SqlHelper().Search(int.Parse(txtSearchCode.Text));
            if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                try
                {
                    txtCode.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["code"].ToString();
                    txtFirstname.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString();
                    txtLastname.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString();
                    var a = dataTable.Rows[0]["gender"].ToString() == "Male" ? rbnMale.Checked = true : rbnFemale.Checked = true;
                    txtMobile.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["mobile"].ToString();
                    dtpDOB.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["age"].ToString();
                    chkStatus.Checked = dataTable.Rows[0]["status"].ToString() == "active"? true :false;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Code");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you use Code = 0; you actually are doing select * from table. But in the btnSearch_Click handler you are always lprocessing 0th Rows from the resultset

Comment: even if i removed code=0 also it is retrieving the record which is first record of the database @PrateekShrivastava

Comment: Coz you have hardcoded "Rows[0]"  --- no matter how many records your query returns you will always read first record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending a `where` class if your conditional expression `code > 0` is not satisfied, which is why sql-server returns all rows from the table `person`. Then when you pick the first row from the datatable using  `dataTable.Rows[0]` it picks the one with id `1`.
A better and secure way is to use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) instead.

```
String Query = "Select * from person where code = @code";
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code",code);
```

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score -1):

When you use Code = 0; you actually are doing select * from table.

But in the btnSearch_Click handler you are always processing 0th Rows from the resultset.

```
txtCode.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["code"].ToString(); <------ See this line you have [0] hardcoded
```

Possibly the record with id 1 is first record in your query Result Set.

Edit:

You need to Loop through dataTable.Rows[] array and capture/process each result.